# Probot: How to use probot without proxy?

Tags: github, probot

Currently [Probot](https://probot.github.io/) seems need to use smee.io proxy to work.

How can I use probot framework without proxy? In other words, use ther server IP directly.

Comment: I believe the proxy is only to demonstrate a local development environment. Have you tried setting it up on a public IP?

Comment: do you mean I set my IP at proxy_url?

Comment: Have a look at this https://probot.github.io/docs/deployment/.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks.

Comment: All the solutions in the above url require proxies, maybe you can try installing smee proxy of your own or GitHub actions.